# Woocommerce Add Product To Cart Multiple Times But As Different items

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have some custom code that adds an item to the cart, a variable product. If i add the same product twice it just increases the quantity. I would like it to add the product again as a different item in the cart.

How would i go about doing that? The item is being added to the cart using a link like domain.com?add-to-cart=3434&variation_id=4434   and so on.

The system i have developed is a product designer. So i may want to pick the same product but design it in different ways, and then add the same variation to the cart.

Is there also a way to send a unique identifier in the url to split these items up?

I want to do it by using add_to_cart but every time i do that with the variation attributes, the shipping ends up with a bug, it basically can't seem to find shipping methods:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(522,1, 523,array("attribute_colour" => "colour","attribute_size" => "a3", "attribute_invoice-numbering" => "yes", "attribute_quantity-column" => "yes", "attribute_cc-type" => "duplicate"));
```

While that code adds the item to the cart, it causes the following:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/****/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping.php on line 291

There doesn‘t seem to be any available shipping methods. Please double check your address, or contact us if you need any help.

It doesn't make any sense, because the standard add to cart code in woocommerce uses add_to_cart and has none of these issues. The same if i use a URL, it works fine!

Answer (score 7):

Try this !

```
/*
 * @desc Force individual cart item
 */
function force_individual_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){

  $unique_cart_item_key = md5( microtime().rand() );
  $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;

  return $cart_item_data;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data','force_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );


/*
 * @desc Remove quantity selector in all product type
 */
function remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {

    return true;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Can I add an if statement in the first function to set certain products to be worth, say, 5 stock quantity, while everything else is set to 1? It should only affect the stock quantity, not the price (i.e. it shouldn't make the price $i x10).

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell yet if the shipping array issue is related. But, if you take a look at the beginning of the `add_to_cart()` method in the cart class:

```
// Generate a ID based on product ID, variation ID, variation data, and other cart item data
$cart_id        = $this->generate_cart_id( $product_id, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );

// See if this product and its options is already in the cart
$cart_item_key  = $this->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );
```

Basically, what we're seeing here is that the item must be completely unique in order to add it to the cart again. Otherwise, it will just up the quantity of the item already in the cart. So, to get around this, you will want to make the `add_to_cart()` parameters unique... probably via the final, `$cart_item_data` array.

Comment: That makes sense, the only thing that i have been wondering, and in the code there is pretty vague. The $variation variable takes the attribute parameters. $cart_item_data i am unsure as to what exactly that does?

The array issue and saying there are no shipping methods it completely baffling me! The product is added perfectly fine with the variations, but we have no shipping methods and an array problem. A simple product doesn't cause this though!

Comment: By default, `$cart_item_data` doesn't *do* anything... it is there for you to do custom things with. I think that in your case, whatever makes the "designed" product unique would be a good candidate for inclusion in the `$cart_item_data` array. Related to the shipping issue... as I mentioned in your other question, you still aren't showing enough of your custom code to diagnose the issue. For example, when (what hook?) are you calling this `add_to_cart` function?

Comment: I found the issue. I was digging into class-wc-shipping.php and it seems that the code there is being a little blocky. I have the shipping errors gone. There were 2 things causing the Rates in the package to return empty all the time. I am not sure if this is down to all my customisations, but i hacked the woocommerce file to get this done (doesn't need to update). Line 352, changed === to == to allow the if to run, otherwise it ended up dead. Then 375 $package['rates'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_package_rates', $package['rates'], $package ) - this filter was wiping the rates out

Comment: Please don't edit core. One day you might want to upgrade... or another dev might work on your code and need to upgrade. You would do better to find the error in your code. Also, so this makes more sense to a future visitor can we keep this question focused on the adding multiple items to the cart and keep your other question on the missing package rates?

Comment: I wouldn't normally edit the core. But in this case i had to. This isn't a bug in my code, its woocomemerce. It also had the same problem on the twenty fourteen theme with all basic woocommerce setup. This will never be updated on this specific project so it doesn't matter. I should perhaps report the bug to woo. The reason the part with === wasn't working is because the function it was using in the if should return boolean, but it was returning an empty string not a boolean. So it is a bug in woocommerce

Comment: Well I can't know if it is a bug in your code since I can't see your code, but if you truly think it is a bug with WC then do [report it](http://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues). Since this question was originally about how to add multiple versions of the same item, if you think I answered that would you accept my answer?

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. Just add unique values in $cart_item_data parameter.